# What happens to an AVAudioPlayer instance after the sound has finished playing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, avaudioplayer

Will it be automatic released by the ARC or will it stay there after i remove it somehow? If it still stays there, is there any usefull data which i can gather from the instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It have the same lifetime as any other object instance, so it's live if retained and autoreleased otherwise. And I guess a `duration` or `playing` or `currentTime` are very useful properties.

Comment: Yes i know the properties of AVAudioPlayer. But i rather thought if i should keep the reference after the sound did finish or not. Or if i should instantiate AVAudioPlayer again and pass arround the new reference rather than reusing the old one.

Comment: I guess if you need to replay same track you can keep the reference - but it will be no big difference with recreating new instance. Usually when I need a replay, I keep the reference and execute a prepareToPlay method after it stops, to make it ready to playback.